# What/Where are the attributes of a function object?

Tags: r, function

By playing around with a function in R, I found out there are more aspects to it than meets the eye.

Consider ths simple function assignment, typed directly in the console:

```
f <- function(x)x^2
```

The usual "attributes" of `f`, in a broad sense, are (i) the list of formal arguments, (ii) the body expression and (iii) the environment that will be the enclosure of the function evaluation frame. They are accessible via:

```
> formals(f)
$x
> body(f)
x^2
> environment(f)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Moreover, `str` returns more info attached to `f`:

```
> str(f)
function (x)  
 - attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 6 1 19 6 19 1 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x00000000145a3cc8>
```

Let's try to reach them:

```
> attributes(f)
$srcref
function(x)x^2
```

This is being printed as a text, but it's stored as a numeric vector:

```
> c(attributes(f)$srcref)
[1]  1  6  1 19  6 19  1  1
```

And this object also has its own attributes:

```
> attributes(attributes(f)$srcref)
$srcfile


$class
[1] "srcref"
```

The first one is an environment, with 3 internal objects:

```
> mode(attributes(attributes(f)$srcref)$srcfile)
[1] "environment"
> ls(attributes(attributes(f)$srcref)$srcfile)
[1] "filename"      "fixedNewlines" "lines" 
> attributes(attributes(f)$srcref)$srcfile$filename
[1] ""
> attributes(attributes(f)$srcref)$srcfile$fixedNewlines
[1] TRUE
> attributes(attributes(f)$srcref)$srcfile$lines
[1] "f <- function(x)x^2" ""
```

There you are! This is the string used by R to print `attributes(f)$srcref`.

So the questions are:

1. Are there any *other* objects linked to `f`? If so, how to reach them?
2. If we strip `f` of its attributes, using `attributes(f) <- NULL`, it doesn't seem to affect the function. Are there any drawbacks of doing this?

Comment: I'm highly skeptical of your #2 claim there.  Unless you've beaten the stuffing out of a stripped function, including indirect environment calls, modifying its `body` elements, and rather a lot of stuff I don't know about,you might want to temper that statement.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I tried using `attributes(f) <- NULL` with a function that has an environment different from `R_GlobalEnv` (and actually looks for a symbol in its enclosure), and it still works. Also, using `body<-` automatically strips the function from its attributes. Considering Josh's answer below, there is even an option to keep these attributes empty from the beginning. Can you propose another test where the attributes are needed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, `srcref` is the only attribute typically attached to S3 functions. (S4 functions are a different matter, and I wouldn't recommend messing with their sometimes numerous attributes).

The `srcref` attribute is used for things like enabling printing of comments included in a function's source code, and (for functions that have been sourced in from a file) for setting breakpoints by line number, using `utils::findLineNum()` and `utils::setBreakpoint()`.

If you don't want your functions to carry such additional baggage, you can turn off recording of `srcref` by doing `options(keep.source=FALSE)`. From `?options` (which also documents the related `keep.source.pkgs` option):

> ‘keep.source’: When ‘TRUE’, the source code for functions (newly
>        defined or loaded) is stored internally allowing comments to
>        be kept in the right places.  Retrieve the source by printing
>       or using ‘deparse(fn, control = "useSource")’.

Compare:

```
options(keep.source=TRUE)
f1 <- function(x) {
    ## This function is needlessly commented
    x
}

options(keep.source=FALSE)
f2 <- function(x) {
    ## This one is too
    x
}

length(attributes(f1))
# [1] 1
f1
# function(x) {
#     ## This function is needlessly commented
#     x
# }

length(attributes(f2))
# [1] 0
f2
# function (x) 
# {
#     x
# }
```

Comment: Very interesting. It seems that `print` uses the `body` of the function when it doesn't have a `srcref` attribute.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft -- Good point. Check out `print.function(f1)` vs. `print.function(f1, useSource=FALSE)`.

Answer (score 4):

I jst figured out an attribute that compiled functions (package `compiler`) have that is not available with `attributes` or `str`. It's the `bytecode`.

Example:

```
require(compiler)

f <- function(x){ y <- 0; for(i in 1:length(x)) y <- y + x[i]; y }

g <- cmpfun(f)
```

The result is:

```
> print(f, useSource=FALSE)
function (x) 
{
    y <- 0
    for (i in 1:length(x)) y <- y + x[i]
    y
}

> print(g, useSource=FALSE)
function (x) 
{
    y <- 0
    for (i in 1:length(x)) y <- y + x[i]
    y
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000010eb29e0>
```

However, this doesn't show with normal commands:

```
> identical(f, g)
[1] TRUE
> identical(f, g, ignore.bytecode=FALSE)
[1] FALSE
> identical(body(f), body(g), ignore.bytecode=FALSE)
[1] TRUE
> identical(attributes(f), attributes(g), ignore.bytecode=FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

It seems to be accessible only via `.Internal(bodyCode(...))`:

```
> .Internal(bodyCode(f))
{
    y <- 0
    for (i in 1:length(x)) y <- y + x[i]
    y
}

> .Internal(bodyCode(g))
<bytecode: 0x0000000010eb29e0>
```