# Redundancy of Function Parse Trees in R

Tags: r, parse-tree

In R, I noticed that the parse tree of the `function` operator seems to be redundant in the sense that its fourth element is seemingly always composed of the first three elements.

For example,

```
> as.list(substitute(function(x = 1){x^2}))
[[1]]
`function`

[[2]]
[[2]]$x
[1] 1


[[3]]
{
    x^2
}

[[4]]
function(x = 1){x^2}
```

One thing I noticed was that the fourth element does store the format in which the function was entered.

```
> as.list(substitute(function(x = 1){
+ x^2})[[4]]
function(x = 1){
x^2}
```

What is the purpose of this fourth element in the parse tree? The only time I can see it being used is if you wanted to print a function verbatim, which you can already do by printing the function, e.g.

```
> f = function(x = 1){
+ x^2}
> f
function(x = 1){
x^2}
```

Comment: good question; I can't find anything in the R language definition, but I think keeping the source reference is precisely about being able to retain (e.g.) comments; if I do `s <- substitute(function(x=1){ ## a comment; x^2})` (breaking the line at the semicolon), then `str(s[[4]])` shows that it's a `srcref` object.  The methods for the `srcref` class look truly arcane ... (documentation: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/srcfile.html )

Comment: Another interesting thing is performing `as.list` on the fourth element, although I have no clue as to what the resulting list represents.

Comment: @Ben's right. To confirm that the fourth element really is just a srcref, see what you get when you do: `options(keep.source=FALSE); as.list(substitute(function(x = 1){x^2}))`. (Or just check the class of the fourth element!)

Comment: @JonClaus: the meaning of the result of `as.list(s[[4]])` is described in `?srcfile`: `c(first_line, first_byte, last_line, last_byte, first_column, last_column, first_parsed, last_parsed)` referring to indices to a low-level object representing the source code.

Comment: @BenBolker: Shouldn't you paste your comments into an answer panel?

Comment: Here is an interesting article by Duncan Murdoch on [**source references**](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Murdoch.pdf)

Comment: May I suggest this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910113/what-where-are-the-attributes-of-a-function-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this component is a *source reference*: it's not easily located in the [R language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html), but its purpose is precisely for retaining the structure of the original source, especially comments; for example

```
s <- substitute(function(x=1){ 
      ## a comment
       x^2})
str(s[[4]])
##  Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 21 2 15 21 15 1 2
##   ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x8a87634>
```

shows that it's a `srcref` object. The mysterious numbers (1, 21, 2, 15, ...) represent indices into a lower-level object representing the source code, as described in the [?srcfile](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/srcfile.html) page (i.e. `c(first_line, first_byte, last_line, last_byte, first_column, last_column, first_parsed, last_parsed)`). As @SimonO101 points out, there's an [R Journal article by Duncan Murdoch](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Murdoch.pdf) that probably gives the best explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Some additional notes:

1) It's possible to disable this feature using the `options(keep.source=FALSE)` (the default is `TRUE`):

```
> as.list(substitute(function(x = 1){x^2}))
[[1]]
`function`

[[2]]
[[2]]$x
[1] 1


[[3]]
{
    x^2
}

[[4]]
NULL
```

In this `list`, the first element is a symbol that identifies a closure object, the second saves the `formals` and the third saves the `body`. Note that this last one is printed in a "standard" way. The fourth element would have saved the input text, as typed.

2) If you type `function(x = 1){x^2}` at the console, R calls `print.function`, which accepts a `useSource` argument. This is `TRUE` by default, and causes R to simply repeat what is stored in the fourth element of the parse list. Setting it to `FALSE` forces R to print the function `body`:

```
> options(keep.source=TRUE)
> f <- function(x = 1){x^2}
> f
function(x = 1){x^2}
> print.function(f)
function(x = 1){x^2}
> print.function(f, useSource=FALSE)
function (x = 1) 
{
    x^2
}
```