# Difference between function objects in R

Tags: r

Suppose I create a list of functions in my R workspace, the same set of functions are also in a R file and after `source()`, the sourced function object should be identical to the corresponding function in the list I created, but this is not the case.

Example:

The f.R file contains  `f <- function(x) x^2`.

In R console:

```
lst <- list(f=function(x) x^2)
source("f.R")
> ls()
[1] "f"    "lst"
> identical(f,lst$f)
[1] FALSE
> str(f)
function (x)
- attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 6 1 20 6 20 1 1
.. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x1b2fd60>
> str(lst$f)
function (x)
- attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 16 1 30 16 30 1 1
.. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x1bb4b50>
```

I also tried:

```
> identical(f,lst$f, ignore.environment=TRUE)
[1] FALSE
> all.equal(f,lst$f)
[1] TRUE
```

Why is that?

EDIT:

In general:

```
f <- function(x) x^2
g <- function(x) x^2
identical(f,g)
[1] FALSE
```

Why would the attributes of f and g be different? Does this suggest one should never use `identical` to test equality between function objects ?

Comment: Note that this does not depend on sourcing from a file; you will get the same result if you define `f` in your terminal. Interestingly enough, this does not happen if `f` is a simple `numeric`: `f <- 3; lst <- list(f=3); identical(f,lst$f)` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: No. If I define it in terminal, identical() will return TRUE. Try `g <- function(x) x+1` `lst <- list(g=g)` `identical(g, lst$g)`

Comment: Sorry to contradict you, but: `f <- function(x)x^2; identical(f,list(f=function(x)x^2)$f)`. We are deep in the esoteric details of R here ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've proved this yourself:

```
> str(f)
function (x)
- attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 6 1 20 6 20 1 1
.. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x1b2fd60>
> str(lst$f)
function (x)
- attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 16 1 30 16 30 1 1
.. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x1bb4b50>
```

These attributes are not identical, therefore the objects are not identical.

More info about these attributes is here:

[What/Where are the attributes of a function object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910113/what-where-are-the-attributes-of-a-function-object)

These attributes allow R to refer to the function's source code. Your two functions have been defined in different places, and so their source code references (such as which file they were defined in) are different.

The easiest difference to see is the `srcfile` attribute of the `srcref`:

```
> attr(attr(f,"srcref"),"srcfile")
f.R 
> attr(attr(lst$f,"srcref"),"srcfile")

>
```

Your `f` function is defined in `f.R`, so R keeps that in the attribute. Your `lst$f` is defined at the command line, so has a blank `srcfile` attribute.

Other parts of the attribute are also different because of how the code is parsed.

Specifically, the `srcfile` environment attribute is different:

```
> f <- function(x) x^2
> g <- function(x) x^2
> identical(f,g)
[1] FALSE
> print.default(attr(attr(g,"srcref"),"srcfile"))
<environment: 0x5b9fe40>
attr(,"class")
[1] "srcfilecopy" "srcfile"    
> print.default(attr(attr(f,"srcref"),"srcfile"))
<environment: 0x5ba1028>
attr(,"class")
[1] "srcfilecopy" "srcfile"
```

I would say testing for identicality between function objects is probably not a good thing to do. The only time I can reliably believe two functions to be identical is if it has been created by assignment from the other one, eg: `f2 = f1` implies `identical(f1,f2)`.

Any other way of creating a function is prone to differences in `srcref`, enclosing environment, and even writing things with or without brackets.

Note all this is avoided if you set `keep.source` to `FALSE`.

```
> options(keep.source=TRUE)
> f <- function(x) x^2
> g <- function(x) x^2
> identical(f,g)
[1] FALSE
> options(keep.source=FALSE)
> f <- function(x) x^2
> g <- function(x) x^2
> identical(f,g)
[1] TRUE
```

But I **still** think you need to think **very** carefully about what constitutes identical functions for **your** purposes.

As for the `ignore.environment` argument, that ignores the environment in which the function was created. I'll write a function that creates functions to illustrate this:

`foo` creates an "adder" function that adds `x` to its argument:

```
> foo=function(x){print(x);function(z){z*x}}
```

So I can make an add-1 function and an add-2 function:

```
> f1 = foo(1)
[1] 1
> f2 = foo(2)
[1] 2
```

These functions are storing the local `x` in their environment. They are not identical by default:

```
> identical(f1,f2)
[1] FALSE
```

But are identical if you ignore the environment in which they were created:

```
> identical(f1,f2,ignore.environment=TRUE)
[1] TRUE
```

If you print them, they look identical (and I've set `options(keep.source=FALSE)` already) except for the environment hex-code reference:

```
> f1
function (z) 
{
    z * x
}
<environment: 0x8e4ea54>
> f2
function (z) 
{
    z * x
}
<environment: 0x8e4fb5c>
```

That's the environment ignored by `ignore.environment`.

Comment: I had a look at this link and it let me know a function has such attributes. But that didn't answer my question why, in my case, these attributes are different.

Comment: Some explanation, which could have been got from the link, has been added.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply, but it's hard to understand why the environment attribute would be different even if both functions are defined at command line. And `identical(f,g,ignore.environment=TRUE)` will return FALSE too.

Comment: That's not the environment that `ignore.environment` ignores. The ultimate answer to `why` is in the source code, and I suspect its because R is constructing a fresh environment in which to compute the `srcref` attribute, which is the right thing to do because these two objects `f` and `g` have independent sources. You have to now accept this as fact and figure out what sort of similarity you really want to test for.

Comment: It's because there is at least one attribute or element which is not identical according to the rules of `R` (and of the `identical` function)

Comment: The problem with asking "why" questions is you can keep asking them until you end up answering "that's how God made it". Or in this case, R-Core.

Comment: Because the only difference I can see is `<environment: 0xxxxxxxx>`, if this is not `ignore.environment` ignores, then what are the environment `ignore.environment` really ignoring?

Comment: For this post I think I was more to the technicalities than to having to give you meaningful explanations why I was doing so.

Comment: Okay, well now you have an answer to the technicalities right through to the philosophy and even a solution to fix it. Can you accept this as the answer now please? Tick the tick?

Comment: Now you get it. Could you explain a bit more what is `ignore.environment` really for in `identical`