# How to print a list containing functions consistently

Tags: r

I am using the `minpack.lm` package and I am trying to add some functionality to its output. The `str` of the model output shows that it contains many functions. I want to add a new function, which I have done and when I print the `str` it looks like this

```
..$ Rmat      :function ()  
..$ predict   :function (newdata = list(), qr = FALSE)  
..$ getMoments:function ()  
  .. ..- attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 115 25 115 46 25 46 589 589
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilealias', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x10a8373c0>
```

However I would like my `getMoments` function to print in the `str` like so:

```
..$ Rmat      :function ()  
..$ predict   :function (newdata = list(), qr = FALSE)  
..$ getMoments:function ()
```

My question is, why does adding a new function to a list make the printed output of `str` look different? I thought it might be something to do with being created in a different environment but changing the environment of my function to be the same as those from the model output doesn't help.

As a reproducible example, use the example from the `minpack.lm` package:

```
DNase1 <- subset(DNase, Run == 1)
fm1DNase1 <- nlsLM(density ~ SSlogis(log(conc), Asym, xmid, scal), DNase1)
fm1DNase1$m$myFun <- function() 2
str(fm1DNase1)
List of 5
 $ m       :List of 17
  ..$ resid     :function ()  
  ..$ fitted    :function ()  
  ...
  ..$ myFun     :function ()  
  .. ..- attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 22 1 33 22 33 1 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x10be3e158> 
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "nlsModel"
```

Comment: Or more importantly, why do you care how it looks in `str()`? Those additional attributes allow R to give you line numbers when you get errors in your functions.

Comment: If you really, really need to remove that for some reason, you can use `remvoeSource()`, ie `fm1DNase1$m$myFun<-removeSource(fm1DNase1$m$myFun)`

Comment: `options(keep.source=FALSE)` Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910113/what-where-are-the-attributes-of-a-function-object

Comment: It's simply for consistency. And I'm also intrigued why the other functions don't have similar attributes printed

Comment: @Natty_E That link I provided offers some explanation on that. "`srcref` is the only attribute typically attached to S3 functions. The `srcref` attribute is used for things like enabling printing of comments included in a function's source code, and (for functions that have been sourced in from a file) for setting breakpoints by line number, using `utils::findLineNum()` and `utils::setBreakpoint()`. If you don't want your functions to carry such additional baggage, you can turn off recording of srcref by doing `options(keep.source=FALSE)`."

Comment: This is in a function in a package I am building though, and nowhere in the package I am building on top of (`minpack.lm`) does it have those things, which is why I am confused their output doesn't have these attributes.

Comment: Ok, interestingly, if I install my package from GitHub, and presumably from CRAN then I see the same behaviour as the `minpack.lm` package. But if I use `devtools::build()` then I see the behaviour I mentioned in my original comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the reason behind the attributes, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910113/what-where-are-the-attributes-of-a-function-object)

However if you are building a package and experience this behaviour, then you will find that when the package is built from CRAN/GitHub, you will no longer see the function attributes.